# OAuth Vimeo with Scribe "Invalid API Key" (Error Code 100)

Tags: java, oauth, vimeo, scribe

I'm trying to authenticate in Vimeo using [Scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java). It's not going over too well. I keep getting error code 100 back, but it still gives me an Authorization URL and when I go to it I'm able to grant access. It's just when I enter the authorization code in and try to trade the request token for an access token it doesn't work. I'm using the Facebook example and tweaking it to work with Vimeo. I don't really know what I'm doing here. I asked [a question earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671742/oauth-vimeo-with-scribe-java/9676459) and was told that I need to include [apache commons codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) on my classpath. Well, I included it in my environment variables and that didn't change anything. So I just added it to my libraries for the project and that seemed to get me a step farther. Now I just have no idea what to do from here. I don't understand why I'm getting this. Here's my code and output:

```
public class VimeoTest
{
  private static final String NETWORK_NAME = "Vimeo";
  private static final Token EMPTY_TOKEN = null;

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    // Replace these with your own api key and secret
    String apiKey = "MYAPIKEY";
    String apiSecret = "MYAPISECRET";
    OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
                                  .provider(VimeoApi.class)
                                  .apiKey(apiKey)
                                  .apiSecret(apiSecret)
                                  .debug()
                                  .build();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("=== " + NETWORK_NAME + "'s OAuth Workflow ===");
    System.out.println();
    OAuthRequest orequest = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, "http://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2");
    orequest.addQuerystringParameter("method", "vimeo.test.null");
    Response send = orequest.send();
    System.out.println(send.getBody());

    // Obtain the Authorization URL
    System.out.println("Fetching the Authorization URL...");
    Token requestToken = service.getRequestToken();

    String authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken);
    System.out.println("Got the Authorization URL!");
    System.out.println("Now go and authorize Scribe here:");

    //I do NOT want to have to do this. Is there any other way I can have this authorize without going to a web browser to do this?

    System.out.println(authorizationUrl);
    System.out.println("And paste the authorization code here");
    System.out.print(">>");
    Verifier verifier = new Verifier(in.nextLine());
    System.out.println();

    // Trade the Request Token and Verfier for the Access Token
    System.out.println("Trading the Request Token for an Access Token...");
    Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(EMPTY_TOKEN, verifier);

    //****Breaks on the line above.****
    //I think it's because the orequest.send() returned a 100 error code
    //Note, EMPTY_TOKEN is declared as null, but I think that's ok. Verifier is not null.

    System.out.println("Got the Access Token!");
    System.out.println("(if your curious it looks like this: " + accessToken + " )");
    System.out.println();
```

Here's the output:

```
=== Vimeo's OAuth Workflow ===

1.0
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rsp generated_in="0.0033" stat="fail">
  <err code="100" expl="The API key passed was not valid" msg="Invalid API Key" />
</rsp>
Fetching the Authorization URL...
obtaining request token from http://vimeo.com/oauth/request_token
setting oauth_callback to oob
generating signature...
base string is: POST&http%3A%2F%2Fvimeo.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Doob%26oauth_consumer_key%3DACONSUMERKEY%26oauth_nonce%3D2861480766%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1331941401%26oauth_version%3D1.0
signature is: 7H/C4F4rK0FYZ5oZGf76Rl8P8yQ=
appended additional OAuth parameters: { oauth_callback -> oob , oauth_signature -> 7H/C4F4rK0FYZ5oZGf76Rl8P8yQ= , oauth_version -> 1.0 , oauth_nonce -> 2861480766 , oauth_signature_method -> HMAC-SHA1 , oauth_consumer_key -> ACONSUMERKEY , oauth_timestamp -> 1331941401 }
using Http Header signature
sending request...
response status code: 200
response body: oauth_token=bf3da4ec799559c9f8b1f8bda2b8d6ee&oauth_token_secret=AOAUTHTOEKN SECRET&oauth_callback_confirmed=true
Got the Authorization URL!
Now go and authorize Scribe here:
http://vimeo.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=bf3da4ec799559c9f8b1f8bda2b8d6ee
And paste the authorization code here
>>unicorn-duqx0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Trading the Request Token for an Access Token...
obtaining access token from http://vimeo.com/oauth/access_token
    at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getAccessToken(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:75)
    at autouploadermodel.VimeoTest.main(VimeoTest.java:51)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 27 seconds)
```

Edit: added .debug() to new ServiceBuilder() and updated the output accordingly.

Comment: please add `debug` to the `ServiceBuilder` like described here: https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/wiki/debug-mode and copy the output so we can give it a look

Comment: I did it just now and updated the output. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

`Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(EMPTY_TOKEN, verifier);`

For:

`Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);`

---

### Edit

The whole key unauthorized part is because this piece of code:

```
OAuthRequest orequest = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, "http://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2");
orequest.addQuerystringParameter("method", "vimeo.test.null");
Response send = orequest.send();
System.out.println(send.getBody());
```

You're trying to make a GET request to the api root (not sure even if this is a valid resource) without signing it. Of course it's going to yield an unauthorized error.

Comment: I think that worked! I still got `<err code="100" expl="The API key passed was not valid" msg="Invalid API Key" />` but it got past `accessToken =` line alright. I don't have time to test it more now, but I'll accept your answer when I get a chance to and it works. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. I've successfully gotten a valid resource and signed the request (after the user is authenticated). It's great. Hopefully I can figure out how to upload videos now, for now though, it's great. Thank you so much for your help Pablo!